# problem with showing \ae inside a formula in xelatex

Tags: xepersian

when i write an equation that contains `$\ae$` and run it in xepersian, it won't show it and instead it shows a blank space. I can only write it in text by using `\lr{\ae}` or `begin{latin}\ae\end{latin}` but these two can not be used inside a formula. I tried this:

```
\begin{latin}
$\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n ($\lr{\ae}$)\pi$
\end{latin}
```

but it's not a good way, because when I run this code:

```
\begin{latin}
$\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \left($\lr{\ae}$\right)\pi$
\end{latin}
```

it says `\right` is not defined!

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.3]{B Nazanin}

\begin{document}

$\to \ae \gets$  %this line gets error  

\begin{latin}
\ae
\end{latin}

\lr{\ae}

\begin{latin}
$\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n ($\lr{\ae}$)\pi$
\end{latin}
    
\end{document}
```

and output is :

[image]

Comment: \ae is not really a math symbol, if you really want to use you probably need something like `\text{\upshape\lr{\ae}}`.

Comment: thank you very much :D

Comment: I have never seen ae in math (and as Ulrike says, the definition in latex is just as a text character although it may work in some math contexts)

Comment: you right. it's not a common syntax in mathematics, but in the field General Reinforcement Learning, we show the history of reactions by  `\ae`